# how to play m4a sound file in systemsoundid?

Tags: iphone

I want to play m4a sound file in device.In simulater its playing but not in device.can help me for this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant piece of code for playing the sound file. This will help us answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You must use AVAudioPlayer to play m4a files.